# Can a mild cervical dysplasia be caused by reasons other than HPV?

Tags: gynecology

I'm not a professional. I have a case of a young adult woman (21 yo), a non smoker, who has a fair amount of stress, a long story of pretty atypical tonsillitis (which did not stop to bother her even after complete surgical tonsillectomy). Two years ago she developed vaginitis, caused by Candida Albicans.

The first cervical smear showed mild dysplasia (type IIIa), in a few months the smear showed merely an inflammation (II) and the next one showed type IIIa mild dysplasia again (while cervical channel had inflamnation of type II). The PCR test for HPV (types 16, 18, 31, 33, 35, 39, 45, 52, 56, 58, 59, 26, 51, 53, 66, 68, 69, 73, 82, 9, 6, 11, 40, 42, 43, 44, 54, 61, 70) came out negative. The PCR tests for common STDs came out negative as well.

Can a persisting vaginitis cause mild cervical dysplasia?